# Could anybody scan through my cover letter?

Tags: idioms, writing-style

English is not my native language, so I could write some not idiomatic expressions which are hard to detect for me.

I am writing to apply for the position of summer intern at the Boston Group.
I have learned about internship from poster in the campus. I want to apply because
I am interested in career in management consulting and knowing that
BCG holds top positions in various rankings of best firms to work for it is
perfect starting point. I am recent graduate and current graduate student of
the Moscow Institute of Physics and Technology. I also suppose that my
academic background in math and physics positively affected my analytic
skills and that makes me a qualified candidate for the position. I am excited
about the opportunity to join the Boston Consulting Group team as it moves me
to the center of the management consulting business environment. Thank you
for your time and consideration.

Sincerely yours,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, the only things I think need improving are your use of punctuation and some minor additions to your writing. Other than that, I think you wrote it quite well. If I were to change it, I would write it as:

I am writing to apply for the position of summer intern at the Boston Consulting Group. I have learned about the internship from a poster on campus. I want to apply because I am interested in a career in management consulting, and knowing that BCG holds the top positions in various rankings of best firms to work for, it is a perfect starting point. I am a recent graduate of the Moscow Institute of Physics and Technology. I also suppose that my academic background in math and physics positively affected my analytic skills and that it makes me a qualified candidate for the position. I am excited about the opportunity to join the Boston Consulting Group team as it moves me to the center of the management consulting business environment. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Sincerely yours,

[Your name here]

Hope this helped!

Comment: Good job fixing articles, etc.  The only thing I would add is that "suppose" seems odd and weak..  I would substitute "believe", "know" or perhaps "suggest".